# Side-loaded add-in doesn't appear on the Apps for Office dialog

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I want to locally (sideload) load an office word add-in that I am working on to test as I work. I have followed all the steps diligently provided by the documentation to share the folder path containing the manifest.xml file but the "Shared Folder" tab of the "Apps for Office" dialogue window keeps showing "No apps currently available".

My word "Insert" ribbon tab shows the "add-ins" ribbon as "Apps for Office" instead of "Add-ins". I don't know if that is the reason.

Please somebody should help me resolve this.

Comment: It sounds like you're using an outdated version. Can you please share your Office client version? Also - have you validated the manifest? If it contains errors / or parts that aren't recognized by your client, Office doesn't load it.

Comment: @MaviDomates thank you for the comment. This is my Office client version: `Microsoft Word 2013 (15.0.4420.1017) MSO (15.0.4420.1017) 32-bit`. The manifest file is the one generated by the yeoman generator just as it is, I haven't edit anything in it yet. I don't know if I have to validate the manifest first even if I didn't change or add anything yet to it. And how is the validation done please? I am entirely new to programming Microsoft Office Add-ins, just trying to learn in fact. Thank you again.

Comment: @Mavi , just got to understand finally that it is indeed a version problem. I upgraded from Microsoft Office 2013 to 2016 and the Add-in  now appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were using an old version of Office client (2013). Please upgrade it to 2016 and you'll have the necessary schema support.

Comment: Office 2013 does actually support office-js add-ins according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/support-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

Comment: After installing SP1 I was able to sideload my Add-Ins in Office 2013 as well